# Click spacebar on the keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have an issue with a resizing `UITextView`

It resizes correctly when user is typing and resizes incorrectly, when i set its text programmatically

with `[textView setText:]`

I want to set its text to blank by doing `setText:@""` and then clicking the spacebar programmatically

How do i click the space bar `programmatically` ?

Here are screenshots of my problem

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: [textView setText:@" "] ?

Comment: I want my textview to return to the original size - it does NOT happen when the method "setText" is called, it DOES happen when the system sets the text by the user typing inside

Comment: You can't click the space bar programmatically through the public SDK.  Text views don't normally change size on their own.  Post screen shots of what you want to happen.

Comment: Clicking the space bar programmatically is almost certainly the wrong approach to your problem.

Comment: Are you using `HPGrowingTextView`, or what?  If you're using that one, there is a `willChangeHeight` and `didChangeHeight` method in the delegate.  If you're not using that one, you must have written some sizing code and it's just a matter of handling the return and resizing your box to the right size.  Either way, programmatically clicking space is not the correct solution.

Comment: no i am using a UITextView, I tried using HPGrowingTextView but it does not meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you've put code in `(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` that **doesn't belong there**.

> The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes
>   to the text. This method is not called in response to programmatically
>   initiated changes.

The solution is to create a separate method that runs regardless of whether the text was changed programmatically or by the user. It will probably looks something like this.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    self.myTextView.text = text;
    [self updateTextViewSize];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self updateTextViewSize];
}

- (void)updateTextViewSize {
    //sizing logic goes here
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, it doesnt work
I do not have any code resizing for the textview

Comment: i do not have the method textviewdidchange in my class

Comment: Your question does not specify how or when your text view is resizing.

Comment: the screenshots explain it - when i start typing a lot of text the textview is resizing - when i click the send button the textview remains the height it was before clicking send, and only when i start writing new letters inthe textview, it turns back to the size i want it to be